# Download a file via a POST request in PHP

Tags: php

I have an API endpoint that dynamically generates an image based on some pass data. I would like to call the API and download the response into a file. Ideally, I'm looking to avoid calling cURL from within PHP and instead to use the standard library. What's the best way to accomplish this in PHP?

The request looks like this in cURL:

```
curl https://localhost:4000/bananas/12345.png \
  -O \
  -X POST \
  -d '[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]'
```

Comment: I'm also brand new to PHP, so please forgive me if I'm missing something in the documentation or this is more obvious than it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use headers:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

$url = 'https://example.com/images/12345.jpg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) 
AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.1 Safari/537.11');
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$rescode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch) ;
echo $res; // This response can be stored in any type of file using below link
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid calling cURL from PHP. Is there not a native way to make requests like this with PHP?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it's clear or not from my question, but I'm looking to call the server and download the file *from* PHP. I don't need to write a PHP server.